# how to Find out users_id with some conditions filter

Tags: data-visualization, tableau-api

i have a table like this

```
order_id | user_id | createdAt | transaction_amount
```

order_id as the id of the transaction, user_id as the user, createdAt as the dates, and transaction_amount is the transaction of each id order.

so on tableau i want to find out users in time range '2020-01-01' until '2020-01-31' with 2 conditions

1. the users are doing transaction before last date in range ('2020-01-31') and atleast doing more than 1 transaction
2. and the users are at least doing 1 transaction in date range ('2020-01-01' until '2020-01-31')

on mysql that conditions can be described with this query

```
HAVING SUM(createdAt <= '2020-01-31') > 1
           AND SUM(createdAt BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-01-31')
```

on tableau i did this

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

on first filter (createdAt) i made range of dates ('2020-01-01' until '2020-01-31')
on second filter (createdAt copy) i made range before last range ( < '2020-01-31')
on filter CNTD(user_id) i made count distinct at least 1.

so it appear 2223 users, instead when i check it in mysql, its appear 1801 user, and the mysql was always right since i used mysql and im new in tableau. so what did i missed in here?

Comment: The calculated field is correct, it seems some other problem is there.  Do one thing create a New field `{FIXED [User]: sum(
IF [Trans Date]<=[Parameter 2] AND 
[Trans Date] >= [Parameter 1] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)}` and check how many transactions it is showing against user 1076 by right clicking and then view data.

Comment: i got it, sorry, so the problems was in mysql, nothing problem in tableau, thankyou very much anil, i have different question again about this, let me make it in new question, thankyou very much

Comment: please take a look at my new questions anil https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64780281/how-to-make-additional-filters-on-tableau, thankyou very much

Comment: You have solved it! Good luck Fachry :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: Take this example

- user1 doing 2 transactions, 1 each in Dec-19 and Jan-20
- user2 doing 1 transaction in Jan-20
- user3 doing 2 transactions in Dec-19
- user4 doing 2 transactions in Feb-20
- user5 doing 2 transactions in Jan-20

data snapshot

[image]

Now if your date range is Jan-20 (say).  If you want users doing at least two transactions before end of date range (31 Jan 2020) and at least one of these should be in Jan-2020 then user1 and user5 satisfy the condition.

In this case proceed like this-

**Step-1** Create two `date type` parameters (`parameter 1` and `parameter 2` respectively for start and end of date ranges)

**Step-2** create a calculated field `condition` with calculation as

```
{Fixed [User]: sum(
if [Trans Date]<=[Parameter 2] then 1 else 0 end)}>=2
AND
{FIXED [User]: sum(
IF [Trans Date]<=[Parameter 2] AND 
[Trans Date] >= [Parameter 1] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)}>=1
```

*this will evaluate to `TRUE` whenever your given condition is satisfied.*  See this screenshot.

Needless to say trans date is your createdAt

[image]

Comment: based on your example, then only user 1 will appear because he transaction dec 19 and jan 20, the user 2 not appear because he's only transaction in jan 20

Comment: based on your data and the requirements, user 2 is not included because he only doing first transaction, instead what i want is the users who doing transaction before last range, and doing at least 1 transaction again in range. let me clear the requirements, i think there's misconcept

Comment: thankyou very much anil, it worked, anyway i want to asking question, based on your calculation, is it return true when both conditions are true, or is it just need one conditions true to return true?

Comment: It will return when both conditions are true.  If you want or condition replace And with OR in calculated field

Comment: hi sir, after i check in my real data using your calculate, and using same parameter with parameter 1 '01-01-2020' and parameter 2 '31-01-2020' . some of users with multiple transaction (more than 1 transaction) but never transaction in date range are appear? instead it shouldn't because the users NEVER doing transaction in date range even he's doing transaction more than 1 transaction.

Comment: It should not! Can you post a screenshot?  See in my example user3 and user4 are not shown. Please also double check the calculation used