# how to make additional filters on tableau

Tags: tableau-api

this is the next part from this question. [how to Find out users_id with some conditions filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64712691/how-to-find-out-users-id-with-some-conditions-filter)

i have a table like this

```
order_id | user_id | createdAt | transaction_amount
```

order_id as the id of the transaction, user_id as the user, createdAt as the dates, and transaction_amount is the transaction of each id order.

On previous questions, i want to find out users with my conditions based on the parameter (thanks to @Anil for the solution)

this calculated field based on @Anil solution

```
{Fixed [User Id]: sum(
if [Created At]<=[END_DATE] then 1 else 0 end)}>=2
AND
{FIXED [User Id]: sum(
IF [Created At]<=[END_DATE] AND 
[Created At] >= [START_DATE] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)}>=1
```

this is the conditions that i want for user and have the solutions like below :

```
1. the users are doing transaction before last date in range ('2020-01-31') and atleast doing more than 1 transaction
2. and the users are at least doing 1 transaction in date range ('2020-01-01' until '2020-01-31')
```

so this is the example of the users who match with this condition

[image]

you see the users match with this conditions because the user_id 5615 has 2 transactions in range and out of range date, and it's matched with the condition,

the questions is, the condition are only to find out the user_id who matched with condition, but how to add the filters, so i can filter transaction user in range, so the user_id 5615 was only count the transaction in range (january, 9 2020) and not count the transaction in september 21, 2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally i found the answers based on this website https://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/creating-a-filter-for-start-and-end-dates-parameters

so i made calculate field with this

```
[Created At] >= [START_DATE] AND [Created At] <= [END_DATE]
```

and convert to true so only the selected with matched in range will be appear

Comment: shouldn't PUL condition be `{Fixed [User Id]: sum(
if [Created At]<[start date] then 1 else 0 end)}>=1
AND
{FIXED [User Id]: sum(
IF [Created At]<=[end date] AND 
[Created At] >= [start date] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)}>=1`? please re-check